# XUnit Class Fixture (IClassFixture) is being executed twice in .netcore

Tags: asp.net-core, xunit, fixtures

Hi I have this class

```
public  class TestHostBuilder : RavenTestDriver, IAsyncLifetime
    {

        public IHost host = null;
        public IDocumentStore documentStore = null;
        public async Task InitializeAsync()
        {
            documentStore = GetDocumentStore();
            var hostBuilder = easy.api.Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0])
        .ConfigureWebHost(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.UseTestServer();
        })
     
       .ConfigureServices(services =>
       {
           services.AddScoped<ICurrentUserService, InitRequest>();
           services.AddScoped<ICacheStorage>(provider =>
           {
               return new Mock<ICacheStorage>().Object;
           });
           services.AddRavenDbAsyncSession(GetDocumentStore(new GetDocumentStoreOptions()));
           services.AddTransient<IAsyncDocumentSession>((c) =>
            {
                return documentStore.OpenAsyncSession();
            });
           
         });
            if(host== null)
            host = hostBuilder.Start();
        }
```

So I have used IClassFixture to share this class context between my tests as you can see :

```
public class ClientAppSettingControllerTests: IClassFixture<TestHostBuilder>
    {

        TestHostBuilder fixture;
        public ClientAppSettingControllerTests(TestHostBuilder _fixture)
        {
            this.fixture = _fixture;
        }
        [Fact]
 }
```

and

```
public class DraftControllerTests:IClassFixture<TestHostBuilder>
    {

        TestHostBuilder fixture;
        public DraftControllerTests(TestHostBuilder _fixture)
        {
            this.fixture = _fixture;
        }
        [Fact]
}
```

But when I debug the code TestHostBuilder  is being executed twice .Why ?
In fact I need the TestHostBuilder to execute just one time.

I followed this method but it didn't work (CollectionDefinition).
https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context#collection-fixture

Answer (score 0):

On your test classes you are using `'IClassFixture'` and not `'ICollectionFixture'` Using the link you added on your question:

> Class Fixture -> When to use: when you want to create a single test context and share it among all the tests in the class, and have it cleaned up after all the tests in the class have finished.

With the other fixure

> Collection Fixture -> When to use: when you want to create a single test context and share it among tests in several test classes, and have it cleaned up after all the tests in the test classes have finished.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have correctly identified that you need to use a *Collection Fixture* but for some reason you have not actually implemented it, your example code is for a *Class Fixture*.

First, we must define the Collection Fixture binding, this is a single class that inherits from the `ICollectionFixture<>` interface and has a `[CollectionDefinition]` attribute.

To do this you must first define

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(ControllerTestCollection))]
public class ControllerTestCollection : ICollectionFixture<TestHostBuilder>
{
    // This class has no code, and is never created. Its purpose is simply
    // to be the place to apply [CollectionDefinition] and all the
    // ICollectionFixture<> interfaces.
}
```

Now you need to decorate any test classes that you want to share the same text fixture with the same `CollectionDefinition` attribute:

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(ControllerTestCollection))]
public class ClientAppSettingControllerTests
{
    TestHostBuilder _fixture;
    public ClientAppSettingControllerTests(TestHostBuilder fixture)
    {
        this._fixture = fixture;
    }
    ...
}
```

and...

```
[CollectionDefinition(nameof(ControllerTestCollection))]
public class DraftControllerTests
{
    TestHostBuilder _fixture;
    public DraftControllerTests(TestHostBuilder fixture)
    {
        this._fixture = fixture;
    }
    ...
}
```

> **NOTE:**
> This solution was updated to use the name of the collection fixture definition binding using a code reference, this helps *bind* the definition to the test implementation without relying on "magic" strings.